# How to print the change in last 2 daily opening prices in R

Tags: r, xts

So far my code is as follows:

```
companyList <- read.csv("~/Downloads/companylist.csv")

ticker <- as.vector(as.character(companyList[1:10, 'Symbol']))

stockData <- new.env()

x <- 1

while(x<11){
getSymbols(ticker[x], auto.assign = TRUE, env = stockData)
x <- x + 1
}

data <- getSymbols(ticker[1], auto.assign = FALSE, env = stockData)

val1 <- data[1, 'FLWS.Open']
val2 <- data[2, 'FLWS.Open']

change <- val2 - val1

print(change)
```

When I try to print the change in the 2 daily opening values nothing shows up. Is there an error in my syntax?

Comment: If that is the case, would you happen to know how I could go about doing this?

Comment: NVM, I took a wild guess on how to use coredata() and figured it out. Thanks fo rthe help!!! How much does you R consultation cost?

Comment: Use `coredata`, `lag`, or `diff`. Your questions are basic and probably not worth what I charge. Feel free to email me though.